# How to recognize "return/cr" as a usable string?

Tags: python

This is what I have

```
# my code
print "This is fun"
said = raw_input("<...")
print type (said)   #checking to see what type "\r" would be 
if said == "\r":
    print type(said)
    print "Error"
    said = raw_input("<...")
print "for the whole family.\n"*int(said)
print "HAHaHaHAAAAA"
```

This is what happens when "2" is entered. The module does what is expected

```
This is fun
<...2
<type 'str'>
for the whole family.
for the whole family.

HAHaHaHAAAAA
```

This is what happens when "enter\cr" is entered

```
This is fun
<...
<type 'str'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ascii.py", line 10, in <module>
    print "for the whole family.\n"*int(said)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

This is fun
<...
<type 'str'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ascii.py", line 10, in <module>
    print "for the whole family.\n"*int(said)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

It recognizes "enter\"\r" as a string
It didn't recognize "\r" in the "if" statement, but does in line 10.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make sure that `said` is an integer before getting to your `print` statements you should be using a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        said = int(raw_input('<...'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number')
```

The reason your code isn't doing what you think it should is because if no value is entered for `raw_input ()` the value is not set to `\r`, it is set to be an empty string, `''`. The `raw_input` function will strip the return character off a value. If `\r` is entered it will be escaped automatically and the value will be set to `\\r`.

Answer (score 1):

In the conditional, you are checking if `said` is `"\r"`. Well, it isn't (in your test, it is `""`), so the condition is false.

To properly see the contents of a variable when debugging, try something like `print '%r' % said` Instead.

The string literal `"\r"` could end up in a string if you use a terminal with CR/LF line endings, but apparently you aren't (or the terminal driver normalizes line endings before passing input to Python).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in print `"for the whole family.\n"*int(said)`

The empty string `''` can't be converted to `int`.

Check if string is empty or use `print "for the whole family.\n"*int(said or '0')`

Comment: my point was "\r" was recognized as a "string" but disregarded later in the "if" statement but then recognized as a value in line 10

Comment: Then you have to put `print "for the whole family.\n"*int(said)` inside `if` right now its not inside `if`

Comment: If you just hit enter for `input()` without entering a value it doesn't set `said` to be `\r` it sets it to be `''`, an empty string and if you enter `\r` then `said` will be set to `'\\r'`